Maximum area of circle sector inscribed in circle
I was trying to calculate general formulas to find the maximum area of a circle sector with known angle inscribed within a circle with unknown radius.
I have shown what I believe are the general formulas below and a brief explanation of how I found them, but was wondering:

Has this already been published or formalised elsewhere?
Are the formulas presented correct?

$r =$ radius of circle, $\theta $ = angle measure of the sector in degrees.

If $0<\theta\leq 90^\circ, A=\frac{\theta}{360^\circ}\cdot \pi\Big(r\sqrt{2(1+cos(\theta)}\Big)^2$
If $90^\circ\leq\theta\leq180^\circ, A=\frac{\theta}{360^\circ}\cdot \pi\left(r\sqrt\frac{2}{1-cos(\theta)}\right)^2$
If $180^\circ\leq\theta\leq 360^\circ , A=\frac{\theta}{360^\circ}\cdot \pi r^2$

When the angle measure is greater than or equal to $180^\circ$ we cannot increase the length of the radius of the circle sector.
When the angle measure is between $180^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, to maximise the area, the two radii of the circle sector subtend a diameter of the circle in which they are inscribed.
Sine law was used in order to find an equation for the length of the radius of the circle sector, this was then transformed using trig identities to get the formula shown above.
When the angle measure is equal to or less than $90^\circ$ the vertex and the endpoints of the two radii all must touch the circumference to maximise the area.
As such we can use the identity that the angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference, and thereby find the position of where the radii touch the circumference using polar coordinates (using a theta value of $90^\circ - \theta)$.
I then use the Pythagorean formula and solved the equation for the length of the radii.
This was then substituted back into the original formula.

I think you need to re-apply the cosine rules for both the $0^\circ$-$90^\circ$ case and $90^\circ$-$180^\circ$ cases. You can tell there are mistakes by substituting in some special numbers. For instance if $\theta=0^\circ$ the stuff multiplying $\pi$ in your formula should be $4r^2$ but yours has $2r^2$. Furthermore, your first two formulae should match at $\theta=90^\circ$ but they don't; similarly the last two formulae should match at $\theta=180^\circ$ but they also don't.

Thanks for your help. I have corrected the formulas, the only thing is the $90^\circ - 180^\circ$ case is not continuous at $180^\circ$. In the new formulas the limit approaches the same value, but the value itself is undefined.

You shouldn't need any sines in your expressions; the cosine rule is the only rule you need. In any case the sines can be probably converted to cosines through standard trigonometric identities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities. The issue with the undefined value at $180^\circ$ can be eliminated if you redo your trig rules.

@JosephVincent It's quite hard to follow your question. Could you explicitly state the problem you're trying to solve (it looks like you're trying to find the largest sector with a given angle $\theta$, but you currently say $\theta$ is "unknown"), and please can you add a diagram (or even better, one for each case you're considering)? You'll also find it easier if you cancel your trig terms fully: $\sin\left(\frac{180^\circ-\theta}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$, and $\sin\theta=2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$.

Thank you both for your help and recommendations, I have updated the formulas and the wording of the question itself. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to attach images but you can find them in the following album: https://imgur.com/a/arlOgpT

Also as a note, I have realised this is quite similar to problems involving finding the radius of minimum covering circle of isosceles triangles. I have found some other questions along that line on the website but haven't quite found anything that asks this same question.

Also with regards to "has this already been published or formalised elsewhere?" while I haven't done a formal search, I doubt this problem constitutes a significant contribution to maths given that it is very elementary trigonometry.

@JosephVincent If you need a bit more of a hand with trig identities, from your current edit, I can help you clean up the 0-90 case by noting that you should first use $\cos(90−\theta)=\sin\theta$, then expand the squared bracket and use $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$. And then for the 90-180 case you should first use the cosine half-angle formula $\cos\frac{\phi}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\phi}{2}}$, then note $\cos(180−\theta)=-\cos\theta$.

Thank you for your help with this, I have updated the formulas in the question. Regarding the publication I believe you're probably correct. I was wondering if there were any different ways to approach the problem, but that's a question for another time. At the very least it might serve as an interesting question for students.

The formulas look nice now. For pure tidiness note how you have an $r^2$ term in all the formulas, so I would take that out and write eg. the first equation as $\pi r^2(2(1+\cos\theta))$. This makes apparent that the radius of the sector is $r\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta)}$.

Thank you again for your help. Have updated the formulas.
